# Non-exhaustive patterns in function Exception in haskell

Tags: haskell, runtime-error, non-exhaustive-patterns

I have this code:

```
import Data.Char
foo  :: String -> String
foo (x:xs) = if (digitToInt(x)) == 0 
                     then foo xs
                     else if (digitToInt(x)) /= 0   
                          then replicate (digitToInt(x)) (head $ take 1 xs) ++ foo (tail xs )
                     else ""
```

input:   `foo "4a5b"`

output:  `"aaaabbbbb"`

this line `if (digitToInt(x)) == 0` checks if the number is 0 if so then it will expand with the rest of the string:

Example:

input:   `foo "00004a5b"`

output:  `"aaaabbbbb"`

and I added  `else if (digitToInt(x)) /= 0` to check for the other cases.

However it gives me:

```
*Main> foo "4a5b"
"aaaabbbbb*** Exception: test.hs:(89,1)-(93,28): Non-exhaustive patterns in function foo
```

error. Which cases did I miss here?

Comment: You haven't included a case for the empty string

Comment: You need to incorporate the ending criteria in the foo function. For example, for when you consume the entire tail of the list. It would also be useful to add when you only have one element.

Comment: Also, single element list case need to be handled.

Comment: @karakfa I'm very far from a Haskell expert, but I'm sure that's not the case. `x:xs` covers all non-empty lists. If it is a singleton list, `x` is that one element and `xs` is the empty list.

Comment: Test with odd number of elements, `tail xs` will fail with empty list error.  Perhaps your input is sanitized already but what if it's not.

Comment: Oh good point, I hadn't seen the `tail xs`

Comment: Caution, the case "00004a5b10c" may not work as expected. Could you specify what output you expect to get for that input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Non-exhaustive patterns in function foo**

This error occurs at runtime because the function has not been declared according to the pattern given in the evaluation. This particular case does not consider the end of the tail of a list.

The solution that I present below is an intention to generalize the use case presented.

Note the definition of the function `reproduce`.

```
reproduce []        .. --Empty list
reproduce (x:[])    .. --A single value in the list
reproduce (x:y:[])  .. --A list with only two elements x and y
reproduce (x:y:xs)  .. --A list with the first two elements x and y and the rest of the list xs
```

> Here is a solution to the problem presented considering a
>   generalization of the foo function.

**The code**:

```
--We import the functions to use
import Data.List (replicate, group, groupBy, all)
import Data.Char (isDigit)

--Grouping by digits
gbDigit :: String -> [String]
gbDigit = groupBy (\x y -> (isDigit x) && (isDigit y)) --ETA reduce form

--Grouping by nor digits
gbNoDigit :: String -> [String]
gbNoDigit s = fmap concat $ groupBy (\x y -> not (all isDigit x) && not (all isDigit y)) (gbDigit s)

--Prepare applying grouping 
--by digit first and not by digit afterwards, therefore:
prepare = gbNoDigit

foo :: String -> String
foo x = concat $ reproduce (prepare x)

reproduce :: [String] -> [String]
reproduce [] = []        --Empty list, nothing to do
reproduce (x:[]) = []    --A numerical value and nothing to replicate, nothing to do
reproduce (x:y:[]) = (replicate (read x::Int)) y --A numeric value and a string to replicate, so we replicate
reproduce (x:y:xs) = (replicate (read x::Int)) y <> reproduce xs --A numeric value, a string to replicate, and a tail to continue
```

**Step by step**:

- Given an entry **"003aA3b4vX10z"**
- Group by Digits: `["003","a","A","3","b","4","v","X","10","z"]`
- Group by NoDigits: `["003","aA","3","b","4","vX","10","z"]`
- Reproduce & Concat: `"aAaAaAbbbvXvXvXvXzzzzzzzzzz"`

**Test cases**:

```
Prelude> foo "00004a5b"
Prelude> "aaaabbbbb"

Prelude> foo "4a"
Prelude> "aaaa"

Prelude> foo "4a10B"
Prelude> "aaaaBBBBBBBBBB"

Prelude> foo "3w1.1w6o1l4y1.1com"
Prelude> "www.woooooolyyyy.com"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what case the OP's code missed.

Comment: I will edit the answer addressing the reason for the error.